# A Category-ish Structure with Morphism Domains containing Multiple Objects?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am working on formalizing software design using category theory.

However the most natural way for me to express what I want is with a Category where multiple morphisms can join into a single morphism.

Thinking diagrammatically, what I am talking about is multiple arrows (from different objects) merging into a single arrow before reaching an object. Kinda like an inverse arrow split.

Please note that I am not talking about Categories where objects can be (say) concatenations of multiple types. It also does not make sense (for what I am working on) to use currying.

So my question is: has this type of structure been researched? If yes what would be a good reference?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicategory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This structure is known as a multicategory. There are many references; e.g., see [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicategory) for a basic introduction, and read the nlab's page http://ncatlab.org:8080/nlab/show/multicategory as well. One very nice reference is the book [*Higher Operads, Higher Categories*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305049v1.pdf), by Leinster (see page 35). One nice introduction is also the [Catsters' video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA2E14CCDF7A0EF91).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In particular, wiring operads are something you might find interesting. Here's a talk by David Spivak on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft0_l_PPO4w . This paper is a good read: http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/informatics/undirectedWD.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of composing with a multiset of multiarrows is that (unless the multiset of domains is actually a set), there will in general be more than one way to do that composition.